# Python - the output is not what I want

Tags: python, function

I have made this code for caesar cipher encryption:

```
 def cleanup(my_string):
    res = ''
    _char = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    lower_char = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    all_char = _char + lower_char
    for ch in my_string:
        if ch in all_char:
            res += ch
    return (res.upper())


def fancy_caesar(message, keyword, true_false_statement):
    keyword = cleanup(keyword)
    count = 0
    while count == 0:
        true_false_statement = str(input("Type True if you want to encrypt.\nType false if you want to decrypt: "))
        if true_false_statement == 'true' or true_false_statement == 'True' or true_false_statement == 't' or true_false_statement == 'T':
            count = count +1
        elif true_false_statement == 'false' or true_false_statement == 'False' or true_false_statement == 'F' or true_false_statement == 'f':
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print('None')
    alphabet = 'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    translated_message = ""
    keyword_index = 0
    keyword_index = keyword_index % len(keyword)

    for character in message:
        if character in alphabet:
            number = alphabet.find(character)
            if true_false_statement == 'true' or true_false_statement == 'True' or true_false_statement == 't' or true_false_statement == 'T':
                number = number + (ord(keyword[keyword_index]) - ord('A'))
            elif true_false_statement == 'false' or true_false_statement == 'False' or true_false_statement == 'F' or true_false_statement == 'f':
                number = number - (ord(keyword[keyword_index])) - ord('A')
            keyword_index += 1
            keyword_index = keyword_index % len(keyword)

            if number >= len(alphabet):
                number = number - len(alphabet)
            elif number < 0:
                number = number + len(alphabet)


            translated_message = translated_message + alphabet[number]

        else:
            translated_message = translated_message + character

    return (translated_message)



def main():
    message = input("Enter string you want to encrypt/decrypt: ")
    print(cleanup(message))
    keyword = input('Keyword for encryption: ')
    true_false_statement = ''
    translated_message = fancy_caesar(message, keyword, true_false_statement)
    print(cleanup(translated_message))


main()
```

What I am trying to get for the output is an encryption of the message that the user enters and it should shift based on the keyword that the user enters.

The message and keyword inputs should be cleaned up by the `cleanup()` function

The cleanup function should 'clean-up' the inputs that the user enters, excluding numbers and special characters.

However, this only works when I enter the inputs in lowercase, when I enter with special characters, I get `index out of range` or I get a very different encryption that I would get if I entered the lowercase versions.

For example:

If I enter 'sloth' for `message` and 'bad' for `keyword` I should get `TLRUH`, which I do get

If I enter 'SLOTH' for `message` and 'BAD' for `keyword` I should get `TLRUH`, which I do not get

If I enter '@!$#@!#@$!SLOTH' for `message` and '@^&$@BAD@*&$' for `keyword` I should get `TLRUH`, which I do not get.

I have been working on this and I have tried a lot of things such as adding the cleanup function wherever the keyword function was inside the loop, which gave me `index out of range`.

The code is one of the methods that I have tried to get my desired output which did not work.

Comment: `print(cleanup(message))` just prints the result of calling the function.  It doesn't actually modify `message` at all, so you're still trying to encrypt any non-alphabetic characters in it.

Comment: so should I do `message = cleanup(message)`? I have tried that already.

Answer (score 1):

You code has a number of issues that make this sort of bug more likely. Let's examine each in turn and fix your overall function:

First, in `cleanup`, you declare a list of uppercase characters and a list of lowercase characters and add them together to get `all_char`. This could be a constant as it doesn't change across executions of the function. Furthermore, Python actually declares a constant string called `string.ascii_letters` which contains all the uppercase and lowercase letters. You could then do the following:

```
def cleanup(my_string):
    res = ''
    for ch in my_string:
        if res in ascii_letters:
            res += ch
    return res.upper()
```

It's actually even simpler than that because Python also has a function to check if a character is alphabetical: `isalpha`. You can combine this with `filter` and `join` to accomplish this entire function in one line:

```
def cleanup(my_string):
    return ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, my_string)).upper()
```

Moving on, we come to your `fancy_caesar` function. This has a number of problems that make your issue difficult to debug. First, the input should definitely not be in this function as that's a violation of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Let `fancy_caesar` just do your encryption/decryption and leave the input to a separate function. Next, you declare `keyword_index` as 0 and then define it as itself modulus the length of your text. However, `0 % x` will always be 0 for any value other than 0 and will throw an error for 0 so you should just take this line out.

Then we come to the algorithm proper. First, instead of doing the `character in message` check, you should do `character.isalpha()`. This has the added benefit of checking for uppercase/lowercase which your current check doesn't handle. Once you've done that, instead of doing `alphabet.find(character)`, you should just use an ordinal conversion to get the index of the character. You can accomplish it like this:

```
number = ascii_letters.index(character) % 26
```

Now, for your if-else statement, doing a string comparison every single time is inefficient so instead of checking the value of `true_false_statement` here, you should do it outside the function and send in a Boolean value. You can also use the `index` function here as well:

```
index = ascii_uppercase.index(keyword[keyword_index])
number = number + index if encrypt else number - index
keyword_index = (keyword_index + 1) % len(keyword)
```

Finally, to your actual problem. The first issue is that you weren't checking for uppercase errors, which is why your input of 'SLOTH' and 'BAD' didn't work. The second issue is that you're including non-alphabetical characters in the translated message. My guess is that because of this, your message of '@!$#@!#@$!SLOTH' and '@^&$@BAD@*&$' would have yielded a message with a prefix of '@!$#@!#@$!'.

Addressing both of these issues, and the other things I mentioned should fix your bug and result in a more readable function for you.

Answer (score 0):

in `def main()` redefine `message` after it asks for the input. Do the same for the `keyword` function :

```
 message = input("Enter string you want to encrypt/decrypt: ")
 message = cleanup(message)
```

Then change `alphabet= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` to `alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`